# in Flutter when i run my project it take alot of time for show me the app somethimes did not show me anything?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I use my phone as a device for run my flutter app

still always like that
Launching lib\main.dart on JAT L29 in debug mode...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do flutter clean,
Then flutter pub get,
And then run the program

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide more details and it seems you are new to Flutter, It's Normal for a Flutter Project to take a few moments when you run/execute it before showing the actual app, and if it still takes much longer than you should run **flutter clean** -> **flutter pub get** -> **rerun the program!**

Answer (score 0):

*you should do flutter clean then pub get and restart the program and Run the project.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).